# Restrict access of files to readonly

Tags: windows, authorization

In Windows operating system, can I restrict the user(according to the registered login name) for accessing certain files in read only mode?

For example, when `user1` logs to the server (taking remote or through VPN) only read only access should be given to him. He will not be able to modify or delete the document.

This is a clients requirement that clients does not need any application to be built. Does MS server(any version) provide such feature.??

Answer (score 0):

Right Click a file or a folder -> Properties -> Security

Here you can modify restrictions about use of the file (as read, modify, execute...)

If you have user group, just restrict what you need

Comment: will it work for a set of users to which administrator will grant the privileges.?

Comment: I have 1000+ folders, going to every folder and setting rights as per your suggestion will become a herculean task. Is there any way where user's login name is selected and privileges are assigned to the user.?

Comment: If you do it on a folder, read only doesn't apply recursively?

Comment: It works for me, restricted read or write to authenticated users to one of my folder and it restricted me correctly the descendant files.